# STL containers move semantics and return by value: how many times of copying get avoided away?

Tags: c++, c++11, return-value, move-semantics

I know that in c++11 the move semantics have been implemented in the STL containers to avoid temporary objects. And people say that now it's perfect to write functions which return by value. But I have some confusions about on earth how many times of copying are actually get avoided. Please see the following example:

```
vector<int> myVector() {
    vector<int> res;
    res.push_back(4);
    res.push_back(5);
    return res;
}

vector<int> v = myVector();
```

My understanding is that in c++03, `myVector` returns a copy of `res`( `4`, `5` copied once), when evaluating `vector<int> v = myVector();` `vector<int>`'s copy constructor `vector<int>(const vector<int> &)` is invoked ( `4`, `5` copied twice). However in c++11 with move semantics, I want to know which copy of `4` and `5` gets avoided? both? Is return value optimization also invoked to reduce one time of copying `4` and `5`?

Comment: In C++03, it's two copies, both subject to elision. In C++11, it's two moves, both subject to elision.

Comment: Why there are two moves?

Comment: Same reason there can be two copies in C++03 - a move from `res` into the return value, and then a move from that into `v`.

Comment: Move I: expression in the `return` statement to returned value. Move II: return value to entity capturing the return value (`v` in your question). Neither move nor copy is likely to happen: they are probably elided. The key change with C++11 is that if the move actually happen it is just a move, not a [deep] copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two copies in C++03 and two moves in C++11.

In both C++03 and C++11 the copy/moves are subject to elision, and as such (in an example like this) no copy/move is likely to happen.

```
vector<int> myVector() {
  vector<int> res;
  res.push_back(4);
  res.push_back(5);
  return res;// <- Here we construct the return value with res
} 

// here we construct v with the return value of myVector:
vector<int> v = myVector();
```

The elision out of the `res` into the return value of `myVector` is somewhat fragile.  In C++11, the `move` that could occur if elision fails is going to be nearly as free (as doing nothing) -- 3 pointer copies, and 3 pointer clears.  In C++03, the copy that could occur if elision fails can be expensive (memory allocation and O(n) copies).

Elision is the name of the operation compilers can do in certain circumstances where two values are turned into one, even if that transformation would cause a change in behavior (ie, it fails the as-if test).

When this happens, the combined value has a lifetime of the union of the two lifetimes.

In the above case, the local variable `res` and the return value of `myVector()` can be elided by the NRVO rule (named return value optimization).  The return value of `myVector` can be elided into `v` as it is a statement of the form `A a = b` where `b` is an expression that results in an anonymous value (the name of such anonymous values has changed from C++03 to C++11 so I won't use it), in particular the return value of `myVector()`.

This cause the lifetime of `res` `v` and the return value of `myVector()` to be merged into one value lifetime.  In practice, what happens is `res` is placed directly into where the return value of `myVector()` is supposed to go (according to the calling convention), and so is `v`, and destruction is of this combined value skipped until `v` goes out of scope, as is construction in the `return` statement and on `v = myVector()`.

Or in other words, `v` is constructed directly in `myVector`.

Comment: So no destructor will be called until v is being destructed?

Comment: @user2345484 maybe.  Elision is permitted by the standard, not guaranteed.  (In practice, you can predict when it will happen).  If both cases of elision occur, yes, only one value with one lifetime exists, and it isn't destroyed until `v` goes out of scope.  Now, `v` could be elided into ANOTHER variable, in which case the destruction would be even later.